# Can't Post to Facebook Page using JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Okay what I want is to post to the Facebook Page as an Page(This is developing mode application only viewable to ne).
I have done with Facebook login.

So basically I ask for `2 permissions` and they are

1. Manage Pages
2. Publish Pages

I can post to the page using the Facebook `graph explorer tool` but can't via my `Javascript` code.

Here is the code that I write using JS. This code is written inside a function.

```
FB.api('me/accounts', function(response){
      token = response.data[0].access_token;
      post_with_token(token);
}); 

function post_with_token(token){
  var message = $('#post_body').html();
  var page_id = 'page_id';

  FB.api('page_id/feed', 'post',
      { message : message,
        access_token : token}, 
      function (response){
        console.log(response);
        });
```

The error object in the console says this

> message: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Both the apps My and Graph explorer have the same permissions granted.Is any new permission to be asked. I am unable to figure out what exactly the problem is.Correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

**I got the answer that I posted below but didn't got why I need additional permission.?**

Comment: The flow for javascript is a bit different.  They walk you through it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3

Comment: I have done with the fb login process

Comment: Your call here looks different then in the link I sent you.  Read the "Make API calls" section.  Also, if you are using a token you generated on server it might not be the same, their client sdk appears to manage the tokens for you.  I'd follow the instructions in their docs that both I am @Jamen posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`publish_pages` has only been introduced with Graph API version 2.3.

Before that, `publish_actions` was used to allow posts on pages by the page as well – now with v2.3, they have made that into two separate permissions. `publish_actions` is for everything you publish as/in the name of a user, and `publish_pages` is for publishing as a page.

Graph API Explorer has API version 2.3 selected by default – that is why your call was successful there. Most likely, with your own API call from your JS code, you did not use v2.3, but specified a lower API version when initializing the JS SDK.

So just specify `version: 'v2.3'` in your `FB.init` parameters (see [Basic Setup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3#loading) section in JS SDK docs), and it should work fine with `publish_pages`.

Comment: Yeah I haven't checked at all because the JS login that I copied from the Facebook developer was 4 months or more before... Thanks man!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I solved the problem . I have to ask for `publish_actions` permission also. So I asked through the Login Dialog and used the same code as above to post to the page!

Answer (score 0):

The error implies exactly what it says.  They've designer their API so it's not going to let you post without proper authorization first.

[Facebook provides a guide on how to give proper authorization to your registered app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3)